# Upgrading a plugin fails going from Grails 3.1.11 to 3.2.2

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm working on a Grails plugin whose main contribution is a taglib. In Grails 3.1.11 it worked ok. I also have a simple Grails app just for testing the plugin. Enter Grails 3.2.2.

After migrating plugin and app to 3.2.2 the plugin shows no signs of life. The plugin *doWithApplicationContext* closure is no longer executed at app startup. The taglib is not found by gsp:s. I did the migration by creating a new plugin and app with Grails 3.2.2 and then fill in the sources.

Sorry for this vague question, but what strings should I pull to find out what's wrong?

Edit 1: Yes, I did the sanity check to have the app depend on a non-existing version of the plugin and got the expected conflict. So it's not that the plugin is totally decoupled from the app.

**Edit 2:** After setting DEBUG logging on packages `grails.plugins` and `org.grails.plugins` a warning message appeared. It came from `org.grails.plugins.CorePluginFinder`. It couldn't find the plugin descriptor (...Plugin.groovy). I examined the plugin jar, found the plugin descriptor class in a file hierarchy rooted in BOOT-INF. Clearly the plugin loader didn't look into that hierarchy. I thought I was seeing a Grails bug because I didn't know about Boot repackaging. I added a post here to that effect, but after getting Graeme's answer I deleted the post because it detracted attention.

Comment: There is really no great way to troubleshoot the problem without knowing something about how the thing is written.  There are many things that might be wrong.

Comment: I would start by creating a brand new 3.2.2 plugin and copy its build file into your upgraded project to make sure all of the dependencies are in sync there.

Comment: I would also downvote such a dumb question:) Very much wanted in the Grails doco is a list of key internal packages for setting a more detailed log level. In Grails 2 the logging config came with such a list by default. In this case the app starts without complaint, and still does not work. A better question would be, hand me some logging settings for closing in on the problem. I was in distress.

Comment: Upvote anyone? Even if the question was dumb the answer is quite valuable. Boot repackaging is hard to find in the Grails guide, it's a Spring Boot thing.

Comment: "Very much wanted in the Grails doco is a list of key internal packages for setting a more detailed log level. In Grails 2 the logging config came with such a list by default. In this case the app starts without complaint, and still does not work." - Feel free to open a request at https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/issues.

Comment: See also [Grails Core issue 10288](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10288)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is that if you run `gradle assemble` on a plugin then the `bootRepackage` task is run which re-packages the plugin JAR as a runnable JAR which is not what you want when you plan to use the plugin from an application.

If you simply run `gradle publish` or `gradle publishToMavenLocal` or `gradle jar` then you get the JAR file that has not been re-packaged by Boot. As far as I am aware this is not a change from Grails 3.1.

You can also disable Boot repackaging all together in the plugin `build.gradle` if you never plan to use the plugin as an actual application or runnable JAR file:

```
bootRepackage.enabled = false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the correct answer, I've tested it. However, it's clear that something has changed, repeating identical build/install steps under 3.2.2 as under 3.1.11 brings different results. It might be a documentation issue. The 3.2.2 guide says to run `grails install` (18.1 Installing Local Plugins). However, this command does not exist. `gradle install` exists, but obviously invokes Boot repackaging, `gradle publishToMavenLocal` does not repackage.